# Mahout core jar in latest Mahout 0.11.0 is missing

Tags: mahout

I am using the latest Mahout release Mahout 0.11.0.In previous version fr example there was a file called mahout-core-0.9.jar.But in this version and also 0.10.0 I have not found any such file.
Where is the file in the latest version.
Please somebody help me.

Comment: And that's producing an error somehow? Please provide more information about you are doing so we can help!

Comment: I am simply doing a recommend program using movie lens data.But DataModel and Filemodel can not find package and giving errors.Which jar I have to add?

Comment: Please update your question with the pom.xml of your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mahout 0.10.0 the `mahout-core` artifact was refactored into 2 new artifacts: `mahout-mr` and `mahout-hdfs`.  You'll need to include those in place of `mahout-core` in any Mahout 0.10+ MapReduce projects.

Comment: But the new errors are given.The errors are given belowException in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 DataModel cannot be resolved to a type
 FileDataModel cannot be resolved to a type

 at com.recomendations.productrecomender.ItemRecomendation.main(ItemRecomendation.java:14).Please help me.

Comment: It's difficult to say without more information about your project.  It would be best to start another question and include the code that is throwing the exception, along with the dependencies that you have included in your pom.xml and a more full explanation of your error.